# I'm trying to filter my data by multiple values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
fee: "20 TEST"
id: "1.11.506157"
info: "[userlink = newdemo1], send 1 TEST to , [userlink = gs6]"
key: "1.11.506157"
time: "2022-09-12T07:06:36"
type: "transfer"


fee: "5 TEST"
id: "1.11.396766"
info: "[userlink = gs6], upgraded account to lifetime member"
key: "1.11.396766"
time: "2022-08-29T09:00:18"
type: "account_upgrade"

fee: "0.00638 TEST"
id: "1.11.396764"
info: "[userlink = nathan], registered the account , [userlink=gs6]"
key: "1.11.396764"
time: "2022-08-29T08:59:33"
type: "account_create"
```

this is my data and want to filter it by `type` .

I'm doing like this...

```
const filteredData = allData.filter((e) => e.type === 'account_create' && 'transfer' && 'account_update');
```

but it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work, you need to check the type on each one with `e.type`
like

```
const filteredData = allData.filter((e) => e.type === 'account_create' && e.type === 'transfer' && e.type === 'account_update');
```

But It would be better to put the types in an array and check with [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```
const types = ['account_create', 'transfer', 'account_update'];
const filteredData = allData.filter((e) => types.includes(e.type));
```

Comment: Can you give me one more idea...I have 4 checkboxes and want to filter above data depending on checkboxes clicked..  like if first check box is clicked i want to filter it by one value only

Comment: @sanjK As I mentioned above, you can use `array` of types and on each check try to add to that array and on uncheck try to remove from that array and use `includes` for `filter`, this is the best way you can handle this.